# Comodules category

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be an abstract group, under which conditions we may have equivalent (resp. isomorphic) categories $Mod_{G}$ and $Comod_{R(G)}$, of $G-$modules and $R(G)-$comodules, where, $R(G)$ stands for the finite dual Hopf algebra of the group Hopf algebra $k[G]$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/445594/320040